# How to extract and normalize matrix columns?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

One of the things I have been working on is to put each column of the matrix of eigenvectors into its unique vector so I can normalize each vector.

```
%% Eigen Analysis
A
lambda = eig(A)
[evecs, ~] = eig(A)
```

evecs is a matrix here.

```
A
lambda = eig(A)
[evecs, ~] = eig(A)

evec1 = evecs(:,1)
evec2 = evecs(:,2)
```

How to Normalize the entries of evec1 and evec2 efficiently allowing for more than two evecs?

MM

Comment: `eig` with two output arguments returns both eigenvectors and eigenvalues. There is no need to call `eig` twice like this. Furthermore, eigenvalues are always normalized, there is no need to normalize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'min' and 'max' with third argument '1' will do the operation on each column separatly.

```
A=[6 2 5 7;
    3 5 1 1
    1 4 7 2];

Ascaled=(A-min(A,[],1))./(max(A,[],1)-min(A,[],1)) % col range is 0..1

Anormd=A./sqrt(sum(A.^2,1)) %norm col=1
```